# CSS: book div overflows after the last book page is flipped, using transform 50%

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-violet-wmdt79?file=/src/components/HuhComponent.vue:300-776

I have a `div` `.book` that represents a book with flipping pages.

Each time a page is flipped, the `transform` of a `.book` is set to `50%`. When it's the last page the `transform` is set to `100`, so that the `.book` with the only visible page moves into its correct position - in the middle of the screen.

However, when the last page closes and `transform: 100%` is applied, while the single visible page is located correctly, the whole `.book` div (red in color) overflows and a horizontal scrollbar appears:

[image]

**HTML**:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="book" v-if="this.hasPages">
      <HuhComponent
        v-for="(page, index) in this.pages"
        v-bind:key="index"
        :front="page.front"
        :back="page.back"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<template>
  <div :class="'page '">
    <div class="front">
      {{ this.front }}
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      {{ back }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.book {
  width: 250px;
  transition: 1s;
  perspective: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;

  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: rotate 1s;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.is-flipped {
  rotate: 0 1 0 -180deg;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

.front {
  background-color: orange;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.back {
  background: cyan;
  translate: -100% 0;
  rotate: 0 1 0 180deg;
}
```

**JS**:

```
const flipbook = (elBook) => {
        const elsPages = elBook.querySelectorAll(".page");
        const totPages = elsPages.length;
        let viewIndex = 0;

        elsPages.forEach((page, idx) => {
          const pageIndex = idx;

          page.style.translate = `${-100 * pageIndex}% 0`;
          page.style.zIndex = totPages - pageIndex;

          page.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            const isBack = page.matches(".is-flipped");
            viewIndex = isBack ? pageIndex : pageIndex + 1;

            let translateValue =
              viewIndex && viewIndex < totPages
                ? 50
                : viewIndex === totPages
                ? 100
                : 0;
            translateValue = viewIndex ? 50 : 0;
            translateValue = viewIndex < totPages ? translateValue : 100;
            elBook.style.translate = `${translateValue}% 0`;

            page.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
            page.style.zIndex = totPages + viewIndex - pageIndex;

            page.addEventListener(
              "transitionend",
              () => {
                elsPages.forEach((elP, i) => {
                  elP.style.zIndex = i < viewIndex ? i : totPages - i;
                });
              },
              {
                once: true,
              }
            );
          });
        });
      };

      document.querySelectorAll(".book").forEach(flipbook);
```

I'm not sure how to fix it. Applying `overflow-x: hidden` works in the fiddle, but I was wondering if there was a better way - to prevent the overflow in the first place